# Push multiple objects with variable keys to array using setState (react-select)

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-select

My goal is to create react-select selects using data from an endpoint where a query var of category (in this example flavours). So I want to dynamically create these select inputs and have set up a component to wrap the main react-select code so I only need one handler function.

Here's my main file

```
const flavours1 = [
  { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
  { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" }
];
const flavours2 = [
  { value: "banana", label: "Banana" },
  { value: "kiwi", label: "Kiwi" }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      test: "test",
      selectedOptions: null
    };
  }

  // Here I want to setState but with the name of each SelectComponent as the key for each object and also push to the existing array rather than over writing it as is currently
  addSelectedOption = (...args) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedOptions: [args[0]]
    });
  };

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles}>
        <SelectComponent
          name="flavours1"
          options={flavours1}
          addSelectedOption={this.addSelectedOption}
        />
        <SelectComponent
          name="flavours2"
          options={flavours2}
          addSelectedOption={this.addSelectedOption}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And the component:

```
    import Select from "react-select";

    export default class SelectComponent extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          selectedOptions: null
        };
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <form>
            <Select
              isMulti
              onChange={this.props.addSelectedOption}
              value={this && this.state ? this.state.option : null}
              options={this.props.options}
              ref={input => {
                this.selectField = input;
              }}
            />
          </form>
        );
      }
    }
```

Here's my example so far: https://codesandbox.io/s/llzw409n3z

So the two things I am struggling with are:

- Pushing objects to state as an array, keeping all of the selected
  values (currently selecting on each different select over writes the
  other
- Assigning each object a key based on the name prop of the SelectComponent

The goal is to get the structure

```
selectedOptions: [
  flavours1: [
    { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
    { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" }
  ],
  flavours2: [
    { value: "banana", label: "Banana" },
    { value: "kiwi", label: "Kiwi" }
  ],
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the `react-select` component does not provide the name of the component that triggered the `change` event. So you will need to add that by making the `SelectComponent` internally handle the `onChange` event and then pass the `this.props.name` to the `addSelectedOption` handler.

Add

```
  handleChange = (...args) => {
    this.props.addSelectedOption(this.props.name, ...args)
  }
```

and apply it

```
    <Select
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      ...
     />
```

Now on your add component you can use

```
  addSelectedOption = (name, options) => {
    this.setState(({selectedOptions})=>({
      selectedOptions: {
        ...selectedOptions,
        [name]: options
        }
    }))
  };
```

but you will have to initialize the `state` like

```
this.state = {
  test: "test",
  selectedOptions: {}
};
```

so that you can spread the `selectedOptions` when using `setState`.

[image: Edit Multiple dynamic react-select]

Comment: This is great, I appreciate the detailed explanation